# Printf and character dilema

Tags: arrays, c, string

I have the following piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main() {
    printf("%c","ACEGIK"[3] - 1); 
    return 0; 
}
```

I know that the result is F.

What does the [3] -1 mean ?

Comment: Very strictly speaking, arithmetic on characters isn't well defined except for the `"1234567890"` characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"AGECIK"` is an array of chars

you're taking the third element (counting from 0) `"ACEGIK"[3]` that's `G`

subtracting 1 `'G' - 1` and getting character `F`

---

`[3]` is applied to the array

while `-1` is applied to character/value got from the array